# React - conditional causes variables to not be assigned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, constants

I am getting the following error `x is not defined` for variables that *I am* defining before my `return` function in React. The variables call on constants that I am importing at the top of my component.

Originally, I simply defined the variables and then ran my `return` function, but then realized I needed to add some logic to change the variables based on the request coming in from the user. It was when I added this `if/else` that the feature broke. Here is the relevant code, the first *works* the second one *does not work*.

WORKS:

```
else if (this.state.form_submitted == true) {
      let parentCat = PERSONAL_IMPROVEMENTS[this.state.filters.categories],
          childCat =  PERSONAL_IMPROVEMENT_OPTIONS[this.state.filters.categories][this.state.filters.personal_categories],
          resultsHeader = this.state.coaches != null && this.state.coaches.length > 0
            ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Based on your request for a coach to help you with {parentCat} - specifically with {childCat}, we recommend these coaches</h3>)
            : null,
          popularCoachesHeader = this.state.popular_coaches != null && this.state.popular_coaches.length > 0
            ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Most Popular Coaches</h3>)
            : null;

      return(
        <div className="">
          <div className="search-results">
            {b2b_link}
            {resultsHeader}
            <div className="coach-card-list">
              {this.renderCoaches()}
            </div>
            {popularCoachesHeader}
            <div className="coach-card-list">
              {this.renderPopularCoaches()}
            </div>
            <div className="revise-recommendation-form">
              {revise_recommendations}
            </div>
          </div>
          {warning_modal}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
else if (this.state.form_submitted == true) {
      if (this.state.filters.client_type == "my_team_or_employees") {
        debugger
        let b2bChallenge = B2B_CHALLENGE_OPTIONS[this.state.filters.b2b_challenge],
            resultsHeader = this.state.coaches != null && this.state.coaches.length > 0
              ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Based on your request for a coach to help your team with {b2bChallenge}, we recommend these coaches</h3>)
              : null,
            popularCoachesHeader = this.state.popular_coaches != null && this.state.popular_coaches.length > 0
              ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Most Popular Coaches</h3>)
              : null;
      }
      else {
        debugger
        let parentCat = PERSONAL_IMPROVEMENTS[this.state.filters.categories],
            childCat =  PERSONAL_IMPROVEMENT_OPTIONS[this.state.filters.categories][this.state.filters.personal_categories],
            resultsHeader = this.state.coaches != null && this.state.coaches.length > 0
              ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Based on your request for a coach to help you with {parentCat} - specifically with {childCat}, we recommend these coaches</h3>)
              : null,
            popularCoachesHeader = this.state.popular_coaches != null && this.state.popular_coaches.length > 0
              ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Most Popular Coaches</h3>)
              : null;
      }

      return(
        <div className="">
          <div className="search-results">
            {b2b_link}
            {resultsHeader}
            <div className="coach-card-list">
              {this.renderCoaches()}
            </div>
            {popularCoachesHeader}
            <div className="coach-card-list">
              {this.renderPopularCoaches()}
            </div>
            <div className="revise-recommendation-form">
              {revise_recommendations}
            </div>
          </div>
          {warning_modal}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` is block scoped. By putting those `let`s in blocks, you make them inaccessible in the parent scope.

Move the `let`s for anything you need (looks like `resultsHeader` and `popularCoachesHeader`) *outside* those blocks:

E.g.:

```
let resultsHeader, popularCoachesHeader; // ** Moved
if (this.state.filters.client_type == "my_team_or_employees") {
  debugger
  // Note this is now three separate statements (with semicolons in-between),
  // instead of one long `let` statement with commas
  let b2bChallenge = B2B_CHALLENGE_OPTIONS[this.state.filters.b2b_challenge];
  resultsHeader = this.state.coaches != null && this.state.coaches.length > 0
    ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Based on your request for a coach to help your team with {b2bChallenge}, we recommend these coaches</h3>)
    : null;
  popularCoachesHeader = this.state.popular_coaches != null && this.state.popular_coaches.length > 0
    ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Most Popular Coaches</h3>)
    : null;
}
else {
  debugger
  // And again, separate statements, not one long `let` statement
  let parentCat = PERSONAL_IMPROVEMENTS[this.state.filters.categories];
  let childCat =  PERSONAL_IMPROVEMENT_OPTIONS[this.state.filters.categories][this.state.filters.personal_categories],
  resultsHeader = this.state.coaches != null && this.state.coaches.length > 0
    ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Based on your request for a coach to help you with {parentCat} - specifically with {childCat}, we recommend these coaches</h3>)
    : null;
  popularCoachesHeader = this.state.popular_coaches != null && this.state.popular_coaches.length > 0
    ? (<h3 className="text-slate">Most Popular Coaches</h3>)
    : null;
}
```

Comment: Wow, completely missed that. Thanks, worked like a charm.